# Hi I'm trying to make my discord bot log the command used

Tags: javascript, discord

Hello so I'm currently new to discord.js v13 and here's my problem, I want my Discord Bot to log a command used into the console but sadly it puts in (random user tag here)#0000 used [Object object] here's the code.

```
const { owner, prefix} = require("../config.json");


const escapeRegex = (string) => {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
};

module.exports = {
    name: "messageCreate",
    async execute(message) {
        const { client, guild, channel, content, author } = message;

        // Checks if the bot is mentioned in the message all alone and triggers onMention trigger.
        // You can change the behavior as per your liking at ./messages/onMention.js

        if (
            message.content == `<@${client.user.id}>` ||
            message.content == `<@!${client.user.id}>`
        ) {
            require("../messages/onMention").execute(message);
            return;
        }

        /**
         * @description Converts prefix to lowercase.
         * @type {String}
         */
    const checkPrefix = prefix.toLowerCase();

        /**
         * @description Regex expression for mention prefix
         */

        const prefixRegex = new RegExp(
            `^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(checkPrefix)})\\s*`
        );

        // Checks if message content in lower case starts with bot's mention.

        if (!prefixRegex.test(content.toLowerCase())) return;

        /**
         * @description Checks and returned matched prefix, either mention or prefix in config.
         */

        const [matchedPrefix] = content.toLowerCase().match(prefixRegex);

        /**
         * @type {String[]}
         * @description The Message Content of the received message seperated by spaces (' ') in an array, this excludes prefix and command/alias itself.
         */

        const args = content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

        /**
         * @type {String}
         * @description Name of the command received from first argument of the args array.
         */

        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        // Check if mesage does not starts with prefix, or message author is bot. If yes, return.

        if (!message.content.startsWith(matchedPrefix) || message.author.bot)
            return;

        /**
         * @description The message command object.
         * @type {Object}
         */

        const command =
            client.commands.get(commandName) ||
            client.commands.find(
                (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)
            );
console.log(`${client.user.author.username} used ${command}`

        // If it's not a command, return :)

        if (!command) return;

        // Owner Only Property, add in your command properties if true.

        if (command.ownerOnly && message.author.id !== owner) {
            const ownerOnlyembed = new MessageEmbed()
            ownerOnlyembed.setTitle(':negative_squared_cross_mark:| You can\t execute that command!')
            ownerOnlyembed.setDescription('That command is restricted for users who is not my owner.')
            ownerOnlyembed.setFooter('Owner Only')
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [ownerOnlyembed]
            });
        }

        // Guild Only Property, add in your command properties if true.

        if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === "dm") {
            const dms = new MessageEmbed()
            dms.setTitle(':negative_squared_cross_mark:| I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!')
            dms.setDescription('Try to execute commands inside a server/guild.')
            dms.setFooter('Server/Guild only')
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [dms]
            });
        }

        // Author perms property

        if (command.permissions) {
            const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
            if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
                const insufficentPermissions = new MessageEmbed()
            insufficentPermissions.setTitle(':negative_squared_cross_mark:| You can\'t execute that command!')
            insufficentPermissions.setDescription('You don\'t have the required permissions to use this command.')
            insufficentPermissions.setFooter('Insufficient Permissions')
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [insufficentPermissions]
            });
        }
    }
        // Args missing

        if (command.args && !args.length) {
            let reply = ':negative_squared_cross_mark:| Insufficient Arguments'

            if (command.usage) {
                reply += `\n:negative_squared_cross_mark:| The proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
            }

            return message.channel.send({ content: reply });
        }
        // Cooldowns

        const { cooldowns } = client;

        if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
            cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
        }

        const now = Date.now();
        const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
        const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

        if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
            const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

            if (now < expirationTime) {
                const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
                const currentlyOnCooldown = new MessageEmbed()
            currentlyOnCooldown.setTitle(`:negative_squared_cross_mark:| ${command.name} is still on cooldown!`)
            currentlyOnCooldown.setDescription(`Try to execute the command in ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)}.`)
            currentlyOnCooldown.setFooter('Cooldown')
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [currentlyOnCooldown]
            });
            }
        }

        timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
        setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

        // Rest your creativity is below.

        // execute the final command. Put everything above this.
        try {
            command.execute(message, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            const commandInteruppted = new MessageEmbed()
            commandInteruppted.setTitle(':negative_squared_cross_mark:| I can\'t execute that command due to an error!')
            commandInteruppted.setDescription('The command has been interrupted due to an error.')
            commandInteruppted.setFooter('Error')
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [commandInteruppted]
            });
        }
    },
 };
```

I would really appreciate it thanks for the help In advanced! (Note: I'm just a newbie please go easy on me xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't log an object but you can log text,try code below

```js
console.log(`${client.user.author.username} used ${JSON.stringify(command)}`)
```